# Is passing with serializable or parceable an efficient solution?

Tags: android, serializable

Im building an android app and in the startup activity i parse a pretty big json file (3.3 mb) into custom objects, or when there was no update i retrieve it from a serialized bytearray. Im dealing with one object with a list of about 500 objects with subobjects, lists etc.

Now i need this data, or some of it in my other activities. What is the best solution for this?
It seemed a lot of data processing to serialize and deserialize using intent.putExtra or using parceable everytime you start a new activity. Is this processing less than i think or is there a way to use your parsing class and don't destroy it so you can use something like

```
Myclass.get(nrIneed).Mysubclass.getsomestring
```

?
This is how i did it when using data for logging or something in my parsing activity.

Comment: Hey @Jasper are you maintaining an array of 500 Objects ? To avoid lot of processing you can make your array of 500 objects static :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application` class to store this data and you can use it across all the `Activity`

```
public class BusinessClass extends Application 
{     
     public ParsedData parsedData = new ParsedData();
}
```

Then call it in any activity  using following code

```
BusinessClass appState = ((BusinessClass)getApplicationContext());
appState.parsedData.getData();
```

For more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: thank you, works nice. For who cares: this is an useful tuturial: http://xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html

Answer (score 2):

You SHOULD NOT use `Parcelable` for objects which may consume memory more than about **1MB**. Otherwise the parsing will fail (at least as per API level 8).

However, in your case, I would recommend you to save/organize the parsed data into SQLite and query it from other activities. This will help your app to eat less memory :)

You may also create a *static* reference to your object, but since its huge in size, I wouldn't recommend you, because then your app will become an appealing target for android VM to kill - when running under low memory circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use your data as a big Json file. At the first launch you should save your data in a database then only use this db when you need to Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete.

If you really want to use your JSON file, then you should make it static (in your application singleton for example).

Hope this will help you